# Visual Sourc Safe: How to take the code backup?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe-2005

I am using Visual Source Safe 2005 as my source control system. I need to take the code back-up. How to do that? Please guide me.

Regards,
Priyank

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using VSS for the first time. Do read thru a few blogs on the basics of VSS.

Refer:
http://www.kevingao.net/sourcesafe-vss-how-to (Read Chapter 2)

Comment: thanks for the info. I will look into the link and get back to you.